# How do I specify types for a function, where they are not used in the function's arguments?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I'm writing some data-access routines, using Persistent. I want my API to be defined in terms of datatypes which represent JSON, but on the persistent side, my datatypes are defined by persistent's templating system.

Given that I have mappings from json to database datatypes, and vice-versa, I thought I should be able to write generalised data access routines.

All was going well until I tried to write the insert function:

```
standardInsert :: forall d . forall j .
                  (PersistEntityBackend d ~ SqlBackend, PersistEntity d, SimpleJsonDataAccessConversion j d)
               => j -> DatabaseEnvironmentT (Maybe (WithId j))
standardInsert json = do
    maybeId <- runSqlMaybe $ insert db
    return $ toApi <$> maybeId
  where db        = jsonToDataAccess json :: d -- Scoped type variable here.
        toApi key = addId key $ dataAccessToJson db
```

(`j` is the type variable for the JSON data type, `d` is the type variable for the persistent data type).

This function has two type variables, `j` and `d`, but only `j` can be inferred from the arguments.

In other words, if I call `standardInsert jsonValue`, the type variable `d` is ambiguous.

I want to call it rather like in C++ - `standardInsert<FooJsonType, FooPersistentType>(jsonValue)`.

How do I tell Haskell what `d` is? Or am I going about this in completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GHC won't be able to infer the type variable `d`. You need to add it to the type signature itself, by adding a dummy argument. The standard trick is to use a *proxy* for this dummy argument, which means the caller doesn't need to give an actual value of that type.

You can get `Proxy` from the [`tagged`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.2.3.1/docs/Data-Proxy.html) package for GHC<7.8, or from [`base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html) for GHC>=7.8, but for the purposes of the explanation I'll define it explicitly here:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy

standardInsert :: forall d . forall j .
                  (PersistEntityBackend d ~ SqlBackend,
                   PersistEntity d, SimpleJsonDataAccessConversion j d)
               => Proxy d -> j -> DatabaseEnvironmentT (Maybe (WithId j))
standardInsert _ json = do (...)
```

and then at a call site:

```
standardInsert (Proxy :: Proxy FooPersistentType) jsonValue
```

Comment: As of GHC 7.8, `Data.Proxy` is actually in `base`.

Comment: Rather than specifying that a function takes a `Proxy d`, I prefer to use an argument of `p d`.  In this sort of code it's fairly common to already have something that matches that type available so the pre-existing value can be used directly, which I prefer to needing to explicitly write `Proxy :: d`.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks! I'm beginning to think I might have gone a little typeclass-happy, and that perhaps I should ditch `SimpleJsonDataAccessConversion j d`, and just pass a data structure which contains the `j->d` and `d->j` methods. Still, I was interested to know if this was possible. Many thanks for a very clear answer.

Comment: @JohnL Obviously it's a question of style/taste so opinions will vary, but I prefer to make it explicit that the value being passed in has no effect on the computation.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam It's more common to write it as `proxy d`, which helps make it clearer. And if you're familiar with parametricity, you can easily see you can't use an argument of type `proxy d` if `proxy` appears nowhere else in the type of the function.

Comment: True, but you can't see that so trivially at the call site.